# Find and delete multiple argument directories

Tags: bash, find, ls

Say I have 3 directories `.git`, `.hg` and `.svn` somewhere in the folder called `lol`.

How can I find and remove all of these?

The following does so only for the last one (`.svn`):

```
$ find lol -type d -name .git -o -name .hg -o -name .svn -delete
```

**E:** This could be done with `ls` too but not without `shopt -s globstar` (since I'm not doing it with `zsh`):

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ rm -r $(ls -d ceaw/**/.{git,hg,svn})
```

**E2:** Another solution woulda been:

```
$ find lol -type d -name .git -o -name .hg -o -name .svn | xargs rm -rf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `-exec` option instead.

```
find lol -depth -type d \( -name .git -o -name .hg -o -name .svn \) -exec rm -r '{}' \;
```

Comment: Yeah, I do need the `-r` because these are _directories_ but that still only removes the last one.

Comment: That's better, but to not print a `find: \`lol/.hg': No such file or directory` error of all the ones removed you should add something like `2>&-` in the end.

Comment: @Det Is that if the directory doesn't exist?  I thought it did :P.

Comment: You can use `-depth` to not get those errors at all. Else it will be deleted and then processed again by find.

Comment: @mariux Good catch, I'll add that.